# How to remove characters from string?

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, strip

How to remove user defined letters from a user defined sentence in Python?

Hi, if anyone is willing to take the time to try and help me out with some python code.

I am currently doing a software engineering bootcamp which the current requirement is that I create a program where a user inputs a sentence and then a user will input the letters he/she wishes to remove from the sentence.

I have searched online and there are tons of articles and threads about removing letters from strings but I cannot find one article or thread about how to remove user defined letters from a user defined string.

```
import re
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
letters = input("Please enter the letters you wish to remove: ")
sentence1 = re.sub(letters, '', sentence)
print(sentence1)
```

The expected result should remove multiple letters from a user defined string, yet this will remove a letter if you only input 1 letter. If you input multiple letters it will just print the original sentence. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Give the user a specific format he has to input the letters in (for example: "E,f,g") afterward split the input at each comma and you are left with an array of letters. Iterate over the array and call re.sub(letters,(letter in array), sentence) for each letter in your array.

Comment: The reason re.sub does not work with several letters is because it searches for these letters in the specific order the user provides them.

Comment: You could do something very ugly, that works that looks like this: `re.sub(str(list(letters)), "", sentence)` EDIT: Actually, that is a dumb idea.

Comment: How about 'for l in letters: sentence = sentence.replace(l, '')'? If you want to remove the letter separately ... just removing the letters as one word would be even easier.

Comment: @Niklas7 Thanks so much for the response! Let me try this quick and see what I can come up with! :D

Comment: @HampusLarsson Haha yeah I can almost picture the outcome in my head but I will give it a go and see what it comes out like :D Thanks so much!

Comment: I was thinking that `sentence1 = re.sub('[' + letters + ']', '', sentence)` would work, then started worrying that you'd have to check the input for `]` characters

Comment: @meissner_ Your suggestion might actually work! I will also give this a go quick and see if its a winner! :D

Comment: I've added simple benchmark so everyone can see the difference between using regular expressions and `str` methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> sentence1 = re.sub(str([letters]), '', sentence)
```

**Preferably with letters entered in the form `letters = 'abcd'`. No spaces or punctuation marks if necessary.**

.

**Edit:**

**These are actually better:**

```
>>> re.sub('['+letters+']', '', sentence)
>>> re.sub('['+str(letters)+']', '', sentence)
```

**The first also removes `\'` if it appears in the string, although it is the prettier solution**

Comment: This works like a dream! :O I had tried sentence1 = re.sub([letters]), '', sentence) but I never thought of defining it as a str again! Thanks so much!!!

Comment: @Deeface Haha, thanks. I provided an edit. The question was actually fun and enjoyable for sure.

Comment: @FaiSafe Haha, yeah the task sounded so simple but when I actually sat down to try get through it, I was like "What have I gotten myself into!?" I will try your edit now! :D

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly we can use [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) methods here like

```
from itertools import repeat

sentence1 = sentence.translate(str.maketrans(dict(zip(letters, repeat(None)))))
```

What this does line by line:

- create mapping of letters to `None` which will be interpreted as "remove this character"

  ```
  translation_mapping = dict(zip(letters, repeat(None))
  ```
- create translation table from it

  ```
  translation_table = str.maketrans(translation_mapping)
  ```
- use translation table for given `str`

  ```
  sentence1 = sentence.translate(translation_table)
  ```

## Test

```
>>> sentence = 'Some Text'
>>> letters = 'te'
>>> sentence.translate(str.maketrans(dict(zip(letters, repeat(None)))))
'Som Tx'
```

## Comparison

```
from timeit import timeit
print('this solution:',
      timeit('sentence.translate(str.maketrans(dict(zip(letters, repeat(None)))))',
             'from itertools import repeat\n'
             'sentence = "Hello World" * 100\n'
             'letters = "el"'))
print('@FailSafe solution using `re` module:',
      timeit('re.sub(str([letters]), "", sentence)',
             'import re\n'
             'sentence = "Hello World" * 100\n'
             'letters = "el"'))
print('@raratiru solution using `str.join` method:',
      timeit('"".join([x for x in sentence if x not in letters])',
             'sentence = "Hello World" * 100\n'
             'letters = "el"'))
```

gives on my PC

```
this solution: 3.620041800000024
@FailSafe solution using `re` module: 66.5485033
@raratiru solution using `str.join` method: 70.18480099999988
```

so we probably should think twice before using regular expressions everywhere and `str.join`'ing one-character `str`ings.

Comment: Tbh, I never thought such a simple sounding task would melt my brain this much! Haha! I actually thought about using the dict function like you have in "Test" But i didnt know how to actually implement it to remove letters in a string. I was also trying the .join approach but with my current knowledge that would also only strip 1 letter instead of all input letters.

Comment: @Deeface: problem with `str.join` that it concatenates "temporary" one-character strings when we can simply use built-ins methods on a target string itself (like in provided solution) that in most cases will be more efficient

Comment: @Deeface: I've added step-by-step description of what this code does and comparison with raratiru solution as well

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation on your solution! :D I am actually trying your approach as we speak. Also you secretly taught me how to benchmark a solution! :D

Comment: @Deeface Indeed, this is a high level programming tutorial. When in production, this detailed mindset makes the difference in the resulting quality level.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
result = ''.join([x for x in sentence if x not in letters])
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work as expected because the regex you provide only matches the exact combination of letters you give it. What you want is to match either one of the letters, which can be achieved by putting them in brackets, for example:

```
import re
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
letters = input("Please enter the letters you wish to remove: ")
regex_str = '[' + letters + ']'
sentence1 = re.sub(regex_str, '', sentence)
print(sentence1)
```

For more regex help I would suggest visiting https://regex101.com/

Comment: This also works really well! Thanks so much for the response! The line where you have regex_str = '[' + letters + ']' makes a world of difference.

Answer (score -1):

```
user_word = input("What is your prefered sentence?  ")  

user_letter_to_remove = input("which letters would you like to delete? ")

#list of letter to remove

letters =str(user_letter_to_remove)

for i in letters:
    user_word = user_word.replace(i,"")

print(user_word)
```

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!